# CarrierWave/Fog/S3 - "Is not a recognized storage provider"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Using Heroku in production, I have image uploading working fine, displaying fine in views - Though, now I'm trying to print the filename as part of a URL and it's returning the error of `Is not a recognized storage provider` on code `'LOGO' => "https://wifiuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/logourl/#{user.id}/#{user.logourl.file.filename}",` - My presumption is that it is occuring on the `user.logourl.file.filename` as that is the image upload column on my User model - All I'm trying to do is print the filename into the URL.

My s3.rb config:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'aws',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
    :region => ENV['S3_REGION']
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

My uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file

  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Gems should be up to date as I didn't specify a specific version. The gems are as follows:

```
gem "carrierwave" #image receiving
gem "mini_magick" #image processing
gem "fog" #s3 integration
```

Any thoughts? Let me know if there's any other information I should provide.

Comment: I'm not certain that it matters, but your `provider` entry in `fog_credentials` is lowercase – the documentation indicates that it should be uppercase.

Comment: @SamSymons I am trying with the uppercase entry for `provider:`, still getting the same error..

@JohnLong can u post the answer if u solved this issue?